# how to create non globally name spaced controllers with angular/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

edit code based on comments,

app.js.coffee

```
controllers = angular.module('Lunch.controllers', [] )
services  = angular.module('Lunch.services', [] )
app = angular.module('Lunch', ['ngRoute','Lunch.controllers', 'Lunch.services'])

app.config([ '$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "/ngviews/lunch.html", controller: "LunchPoolController" } )
])
```

controllers.js.coffee

```
controllers.controller('LunchPoolController', ($scope, LunchMates) ->
    # $scope.lunchers = ["some data"]
  LunchMates.getLunchMates().then (data) ->
    $scope.lunchers = data 
)
```

services.js.coffee

```
services.factory 'LunchMates', ($rootScope, $q, $http) ->
  LunchMates = 
    getLunchMates: () ->
      d = $q.defer(); 
      $http.get('/lunchers').then (response, status) ->
        d.resolve(response.data)
      return d.promise

  return LunchMates
```

chrome console is coughing up

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: controllers is not defined controllers.js?body=1:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: services is not defined services.js?body=1:2
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LunchMatesProvider <- LunchMates
```

Comment: looking at page 36 of ng, book, i should be able to use something like var app = angular.module('app', []); app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "hello";
});  but that isn't working in this case, and i've just edited the above to fix that Lunch = angular.module line

Comment: Oh, sorry, It seems you're loading the files in the wrong order. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your modules defined in the order in which they are dependent.

so load first your

services.js

```
var services = angular.module('Lunch.services',[])
services.factory('MyLunchFactory',function($http){ ... });
```

then controllers.js

```
var controllers = angular.module('Lunch.controllers',[]);
controllers.controller('LunchPoolController',function($scope){ ... });
```

finally your app.js (with the name that is on your ng-app)

```
var app = angular.module('Lunch',['Lunch.controllers','Lunch.services']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    //setup routes....
}]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is working for me, I posted my edits, did I miss something ?

Comment: out of curiosity, what order do these files get loaded and how did you know that ?

Comment: You most likely use an ng-app directive. On module declaration angular will examine this directive And automatically bootstrap your app. After this bootstrap occurs you can no longer add controllers / modules etc.  So you have to make sure your ng-app module ('Lunch') is loaded last. It can then find your dependent modules, and automatically bootstrap